Interrupt expensive SciPy calculations
Is there a way to programmatically interrupt expensive operations like curve_fit from SciPy? In the application I’m developing for a client, I need to perform expensive calculations with maxfev set (upon request) to 1,000,000,000. I’m working with PyQt6, and the computation is moved to another thread using a worker with QThread. The problem is that sometimes the computation takes too long and crashes the application. What I need is the ability to set a timeout or allow the user to stop the operation, which would not only interrupt the execution thread of the calculation but also stop the calculation itself (i.e., curve_fit) by raising an exception. I’ve already tried various mechanisms, including handling with multiprocessing or concurrent.futures, but none of these solutions work. The thread is interrupted, but it seems that the computation operation remains hanging in the background, leaving the application quite unresponsive. I appreciate any suggestions on this matter.

If an operation isn't interruptible, it, well, isn't. Anyway: multiprocessing (a subprocess) would work ("none of these solutions work" doesn't tell us much) and a multiprocessing subprocess can be killed at will, if you're willing to pay the serialization/deserialization price of moving your data to it.

multiprocessing should allow you to kill the thread, but you may have to use an aggressive option to do so. Like try sending a SIGTERM, if it doesn't work, send a SIGQUIT, and if it still doesn't stop, do a SIGKILL

@tbrugere multiprocessing does not create threads, it creates processes (and this is an important difference to be aware of).

you're right, i meant process. too late to edit

You wrote that you want to interrupt things by raising an exception. Why can't you raise an exception from the callable that you pass to curve_fit? Like, wrap your existing callable with a callable that tracks e.g. the number of iterations or the system time and raises an exception if it takes too long. If this sounds reasonable, I'll write it up as an answer.

As hinted above, multiprocessing is probably the only solution you have. If it didn't "work" for you then you probably did something wrong, but we cannot help you with that until you provide a proper [mre]. You should also clarify what should eventually raise the exception on what, and why you need that.

Doesn't answer the specific question, but it may be possible to make the calculation significantly faster so that you don't need to do this. You could do this with cminpack_numba - disclaimer I'm the author.
